Having issue with android play core dependency in android studio
[Prevents app release in Google Play Console] com.google.android.play:core version 1.10.3 has been reported as problematic by its author and will block publishing of your app to Play Console.


Replace
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

with
// So, make sure you also include that repository in your project's build.gradle file.
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'

// For Kotlin users also add the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Update:
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0'


The Play Core Library has been partitioned into multiple per-feature Android libraries to reduce the size Play Core add and allows for faster release cycles of the individual features.
The features are:

Play Feature Delivery
Play In-App Review
Play In-App Update
Play Asset Delivery

Depending on your use case, for instance, if the feature you want to implement is the In-App review, in your project's build.gradle file
Replace

implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

with
implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'

// For Kotlin users, add the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Review

implementation 'com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.1'

